# How to set up realip module in nginx

Tags: nginx, debian, cloudflare

I want to use http_realip_module in nginx and Cloudflare. `nginx -V` returns

```
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0d  26 Jan 2017 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017)  
TLS SNI support enabled  
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-F3HeH5/nginx-1.10.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-F3HeH5/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-F3HeH5/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-F3HeH5/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-F3HeH5/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-F3HeH5/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

As you can see there is `--with-http_realip_module`.
`/etc/nginx/modules-available` is empty, `/etc/nignx/modules-enabled` returns

```
razem 24K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K kwi 23 15:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4,0K kwi 23 19:53 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   57 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-auth-pam.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   56 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-dav-ext.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-http-echo.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-echo.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   54 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-http-geoip.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-geoip.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   61 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-http-image-filter.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-image-filter.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   60 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-subs-filter.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   62 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-upstream-fair.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   60 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-xslt-filter.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   48 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-mail.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-mail.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   50 kwi 23 15:58 50-mod-stream.conf -> /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-stream.conf
```

I have configuration from Cloudflare [right there](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-), but I don't know where to put it. Do I have to create config? Where, how should I name it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to paste it inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and reload using `sudo service nginx reload`.
Remember to test config first using `nginx -t`.

Comment: Using Debian, the configuration lines should take place in say `/etc/nginx/conf.d/realip.conf`.

Comment: What do you mean by pasting it inside?  can you show an example?

Comment: I.e. in question is link to Cloudflare, you have to select nginx and you have config parameters there. So you have to copy that params, edit `nginx.conf` (or `realip.conf` as greg said) and paste that configuration at the end of that file. Save and reload nginx.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you are using Cloudflare and IP adresses are known.

Paste the following lines in to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-cloudflase-realip.conf`

```
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;

#real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

Note: For others you can set the following lines in to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-realip.conf`

```
set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
set_real_ip_from  172.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from  192.168.0.0/16;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
```

Be sure you have the following line in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Comment: To Include the original visitor IP in your logs, add the variables `$http_x_forwarded_for` in the log_format directive. :)

Comment: Cloudflare IPs: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/